# Add new alias to keystore

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I accidently deleted my kestore certificate using this command,

```
keytool -delete -alias mydomain -keystore keystore.jks
```

Is it somehow possible to add another alias to existing key?
Also I don't have the .crt of old certificate.